# What the eror in my code as whenevery i run it it comes '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'...i think there is an eror in para:

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, user-defined-functions

```
list1=list(map(int, input().split()))
max_num=[0]

for number in list1:
    if number > max_num:
        max_num = number

def counter(lis1,max_num):
    count = 0
    for number in lis1:
        if (number == max_num):
            count = count + 1
    return count

print(f'{max_num} has occured {counter} time')
```

Comment: `max_num=[0]` probably wants to be `max_num=0`

Comment: Please write your full question in the body of the post instead of writing it in the title. Write short overall questions in title